# Как правильно сделать отступы чтобы текст на вылезал за фон?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как правильно сделать отступы чтобы текст на вылезал за фон?.

```css
.wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("../images/bg_1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 570px;
  height: 106px;
  left: 100px;
  padding-top: 102px;
  font-family: 'pt_serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 575px;
  height: 142px;
  left: 101px;
  padding-top: 234px;
  font-family: 'pt-sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .wrap div:nth-child(1),
  .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .wrap div:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_bg">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>Мы вкладываем душу в совершенствование вкуса</div>
    <div>Мы относимся к своему бренду как к носителю наших уникальных преимуществ и всегда преподносим его "с поля к столу". Мы используем наши уникальные знания и опыт для выращивания и отбора для наших продуктов самых лучших урожаев с плодородных южно-украинских
      полей.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавила:

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Результат (текст не вылазит):

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("../images/bg_1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  
  background: #000;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 570px;
  height: 106px;
  left: 100px;
  padding-top: 102px;
  font-family: 'pt_serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 575px;
  height: 142px;
  left: 101px;
  padding-top: 234px;
  font-family: 'pt-sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .wrap div:nth-child(1),
  .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .wrap div:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_bg">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>Мы вкладываем душу в совершенствование вкуса</div>
    <div>Мы относимся к своему бренду как к носителю наших уникальных преимуществ и всегда преподносим его "с поля к столу". Мы используем наши уникальные знания и опыт для выращивания и отбора для наших продуктов самых лучших урожаев с плодородных южно-украинских
      полей.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```